# User-defined SPARQL aggregation functions in Virtuoso

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I want to implement a user-defined boolean aggregation function in SPARQL and I am checking whether how easy/feasible is this in different SPARQL engines. In regards to Virtuoso, is it possible? If so, where could I find further information about it? By googling I found how to do it for SQL but not for SPARQL: http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/aggregates/

Thanks your attention and help,
Luis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're more than halfway there.

Virtuoso lets you use SQL functions, both built-in (`bif:`) and user-defined (`sql:`), within SPARQL queries, as [discussed in the documentation](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfsqlfromsparql/):

> A `SPARQL` expression can contain calls to Virtuoso/PL functions and built-in SQL functions in both the `WHERE` clause and in the result set. Two namespace prefixes, `bif` and `sql` are reserved for these purposes. When a function name starts with the `bif:` namespace prefix, the rest of the name is treated as the name of a SQL BIF (Built-In Function). When a function name starts with the `sql:` namespace prefix, the rest of the name is treated as the name of a Virtuoso/PL function owned by `DBA` with database qualifier `DB`, e.g., `sql:example(...)` is converted into `DB.DBA."example"(...)`.

ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.

Comment: That is great news! Thanks!